# What does n_jobs=-1 do in XGBClassifier from xgboost?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, xgbclassifier

What does the n_jobs=-1 means do when creating a XGBClassifier object?

```
xgbc = XGBClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The n_jobs parameter defines the number of parallel threads to run xgboost. When passing "-1" to the "n_jobs" parameter, the computation will be dispatched to all parallel threads available in the computer.

You can get more details from the official API Reference: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier

Comment: Not sure it's worth preserving this question, it's so easily answered by the documentation. And your answer is a bit less precise as it's threads, specifically. Link to the docs: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier

Comment: In the documentation it doesn't mention the effect of  "n_jobs = -1". I'll update the answer to include the description from the Docs.